# Openlayers navigation control not visible

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, openlayers

I have a pretty basic setup of a map with openlayers, and just 3 controls, built in an MVC project.  For soem reason though, the navigation control and the panzoombar do not show (although the mouseposition one does).  I see them for an instant while the map loads, but then they disappear.  Below is my code that i use to make this happen.  Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
        function initNormMap() {
        var map;
        OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH = 72;
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('divmap', {
            controls: [
                        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition()
            ], units: 'm',
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
            displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
        });
        //http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/AvailableWMSServices
        var ol_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS",
                    "http://labs.metacarta.com/wms/vmap0",
                      { layers: 'basic' });

        var osm_wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
        map.addLayers([osm_wms]);
        var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
        var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
        var position = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-98, 39).transform(fromProjection, toProjection);
        var zoom = 4;
        map.setCenter(position, zoom);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem turned out to be with MVC4 bundling, which doesn't seem to work well with openlayers at all.  I had in my BundleConfig.cs file:

```
var openBun = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/openlayerjs").Include("~/OpenLayers-2.10/OpenLayers.js");
        openBun.CdnPath = @"http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/2.11/OpenLayers.js";
        bundles.Add(openBun);
```

and in my actual .cshtml page:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/openlayerjs")
```

I even tried it without the CDNPath, and still got the same issue each time.  changed to just straight

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/OpenLayers-2.10/OpenLayers.js")"></script>
```

and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason bundling fails is becuase **unless explicitly specified**, OpenLayers will **try to load 'style.css' relative to the script file**.

Example:

```
Script: /scripts/OpenLayers-2.13.1/OpenLayers.js
Style:  /scripts/OpenLayers-2.13.1/theme/default/style.css
```

When the scripts are bundled, the script path becomes something like:

```
/scripts/master-bundle?v=Jg4I5oThMOtPHMDHusv30zPkDMVHcvHtjoLyWPwIC1A1
```

and 'style.css' fails to load, causing images not to show.

The **solution** is to be found **in the source** of OpenLayers.js

```
 * Please remember that when your OpenLayers script is not named 
 * "OpenLayers.js" you will have to make sure that the default theme is 
 * loaded into the page by including an appropriate <link>-tag, 
 * e.g.:
 * 
 * (code)
 *   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/default/style.css"  type="text/css">
 * (end code)
```

If you're bundling the script file, **you need to explicitly reference 'style.css'**, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/OpenLayers-2.13.1/theme/default/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

**UPDATE:**
You need to set `OpenLayers.ImgPath` as well, so here's a **new approach** that covers all:

*openlayers-fix.js*

```
var basePath = '/Scripts/OpenLayers-2.13.1/';
var cssPath = basePath + 'theme/default/style.css';
var imgpath = basePath + 'img/';


// load stylesheet
$('<link>')
    .appendTo('head')
    .attr({ type: 'text/css', rel: 'stylesheet' })
    .attr('href', cssPath);

// set image path
OpenLayers.ImgPath = imgpath;
```

*bundle config*

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/openlayers")
       .Include(new[]
           {
               "~/Scripts/OpenLayers-2.13.1/OpenLayers.js",
               "~/Scripts/OpenLayers-2.13.1/lang/nl.js",
               "~/Scripts/openlayers-fix.js"
           })
```